# Where to learn about bytecode generation?

Tags: virtual-machine, code-generation

I'm trying to learn about generating code for a virtual machine. Where can I find out more about this, any useful books that are about this topic? This is probably a bad question for Stack Overflow, but I'm really confused and I've searched everywhere for a good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off-topic, however:

read Queinnec's [Lisp in Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html)

study the source code of [lua](http://www.lua.org/) (5.2 or newer), of [nekoVM](http://nekovm.org/), of Ocaml bytecode interpreter (file [`byterun/interp.c`](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/trunk/byterun/interp.c?view=markup)), and of [parrot](http://docs.parrot.org/parrot/latest/html/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out :) But for future reference, any other stack exchange thing for questions like these?